# How can redirect a custom domain to sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, redirect, domain, dns, m365

I would like to redirect a custom domain https://whatever.com to https://whatever.sharepoint.com (SPO), but after add an CNAME entry I got the following error:

*Our services aren't available right now. We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.*

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

SPRegards

Comment: Can't you do that at your DNS provider? I know I can

Comment: @BennySkogberg when doing it on the DNS provider the above error occurs.

Comment: Add a support ticket, cause they shouldn't determine when you want a permanent redirect

Comment: @BennySkogberg to MS or the DNS provider?

Comment: DNS provider since they're sending the error message